# Angular2 Dynamic Component Loader with HTTP query

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I'm trying to load data via HTTP GET in one component and then I need to use this data in child component that loaded dynamically.

Here's the code:

```
ngOnInit(){
this.accountService.getPersonalInfo().subscribe(
        response => {
            this.Account = response.json();

            this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(HeaderComponent, this.elementRef, 'header')
                .then(compRef => {
                        compRef.instance.Account=this.Account;
                    }
                );
        }
        );
}
```

In child component (HeaderComponent) I can use `this.Account` to get this data. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just provide in an ancestor component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header-cmp',
  ...
})
class HeaderCmp {
  constructor(private account:AccountService) {
    this.account.someObservable.subscribe(...); // or whatever
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-cmp',
  providers: [AccountService],
  ...
})
class ParentCmp {
  constructor(private account:AccountService) {
    // set some values
  }
}
```

The component where you provide the "service" can be the component where `this.dcl.loadIntoLocation(...)` is actually executed or some other ancestor component further up the chain.

Comment: But then it will be two similar http queries - one in the parent component and other in the child, right? I need to use the data (this.Account) in both components

Comment: Angulars DI maintains a single instance per provider. The `ParentCmp` will get the instance of the provider on itself. For the `HeaderCmp` DI will look upwards until it finds a provider for `AccountService`. If you don't add it anywhere in between (only applicable if `ParentCmp` and `HeaderCmp` are not in a direct parent-child relation) then DI will find the provider of `ParentCmp` and pass it to `HeaderCmp` as well. This way both components get a reference to the same `AccountService` instance.